# rotate3d or matrix3d transition not working correct in IE10

Tags: css-transitions, css-animations, internet-explorer-10

I try to make a flip-page effect in IE10.

When i make the transformation with  `rotateY(180deg)` it works well,
but with `rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg)` it makes a strange flip at 90deg (only on IE10!).

Have a look at this jsfiddle on IE10: http://jsfiddle.net/wG6gk/2/

Is this a IE Bug or does the container need any additional CSS attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Css3 is in draft mode, each browser can have it's own perception of Css3.
I don't think that it is a bug.
According to my experience in css3, `rotate3d` is one the css3 properties that is hardware accelerated (more  accelerated than `rotateX` and `rotateY`). But in this case you can't use `rotate3d` for IE, because it will not act the way you expect here.

Comment: thx, yes i want to use rotate3d because it is hardware-accelerated (like matrix3d). Every other browser work fine with rotate3d,but IE10 not. I think i have to use the slower rotateY...

Comment: Most of css3 Properties are Hardware-Accelerated in IE10. You'd better check them real-time with an advanced task-manager like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).